# Azure: Best way to check for a new json file on external server

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification

I'm writting a mobile application which should receive a notification if a `JSON` file on an external server is changed.

I would love to do this in Azure by checking every 20 seconds if the file has changed (and if it's the case I send a push-notification).

What's the best way to do this in Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Scheduling options in Azure](http://mattmilner.com/Milner/Blog/post/2014/02/10/How-many-schedulers-do-we-need-in-Windows-Azure.aspx)

- [Azure Cloud Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/cloud-services/)
- [Azure Scheduler](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/scheduler/) - for heavier workloads invoked on other services
- [Azure Websites WebJobs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) - for lightweight workloads
- [Azure Mobile Services Scheduled Job](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-schedule-recurring-tasks/)

For your situation probably use Azure Mobile Services to [periodically schedule a job](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-schedule-recurring-tasks/) and use Mobile Services to send push notifications

Comment: WebJobs was exactly what I was looking for. I hope the development state will soon change from Preview to Stable..